# Setting up openIMAJ in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, libraries, openimaj

I'a having trouble setting up openIMAJ in Intellij Idea. I've checked out the library from svn and added it to the project via File->Project structure->Libraries. The code completion in IDEA kinda works (completes import statements) but when I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
object openimaj is not a member of package org
import org.openimaj.video.capture._
       ^
```

My friend said it was a project structure issue but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can't just add the OpenIMAJ sources to IntelliJ - as you've discovered, that won't work. To add OpenIMAJ to an existing project manually, you'd have to download/compile all the individual module jars, and add those with their dependencies (and the dependencies dependencies...).

Instead, I'd suggest that you create a new OpenIMAJ project using maven (following the instructions in the tutorial: http://www.openimaj.org/tutorial/getting-started-with-openimaj-using-maven.html), and then open that in IntelliJ. Maven will take care of automatically take care of including all the OpenIMAJ libraries into your project, as well as their dependencies. IntelliJ natively supports maven projects, so you just need to open the project directory from IntelliJ to load it; it will take a while for IntelliJ and maven to download and set up the dependencies the first time however.